# Aurman: remove packages that are reported as neither in the repos nor AUR

Tags: pacman, aur

I have installed `aurman` from the AUR, and every time I install a package, it says that packages are neither in the repos nor the AUR. Is there a way to remove them without removing them manually like `sudo pacman -Rsn <package 1> <package 2>...`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove them without actually removing them'?

Comment: @sudodus I meant `manually`. Fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pacman, by definition, can only know about packages that are in its database; so either those installed by pacman or an AUR helper that wraps pacman/makepkg.

Anything that you have installed without pacman, eg., using something like pip or gem, is *your responsibility*.

So even your example (`sudo pacman -Rsn <package>`) will not work as these packages *are not in the database*. There is a [process outlined on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Identify_files_not_owned_by_any_package) to help identify potential candidates, but they still must be removed manually (ie., with `rm`), and **with caution**.

The only other category of package that *could* be covered by this scenario is an AUR package that has subsequently been deleted, and then it would be necessary to use pacman to remove it; this could be done with `# pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)`.

Comment: I do not understand how your last command is supposed to do what you say it does: `pacman -Qtdq` lists orphans, (according to the man page: _packages that were installed as dependencies but are no longer required by any installed package._). This is very different from a package that is locally installed but no longer exists on the repository.